# How to extract string in Python

Tags: python, substring

I want to extract specific string from a string, but it shows error. Why can't I use the find as index to extract string ?

Here is my code

```
string = 'ABP'
p_index = string.find('P')
s = string[0, p_index]
print(s)

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 1):

`s = string[0, p_index]` isn't a valid syntax in python, you should rather do:

```
s = string[0:p_index]
```

Since an omitted first index defaults to zero, this returns the same result:

```
s = string[:p_index]
```

I'd recommend reading [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) for reference on Python string's slicing and it's syntax in general.

Answer (score 1):

You should change this line:

```
s = string[0, p_index]
```

with

```
s = string[p_index]
```

You don't need to put anything rather than the index of the letter to get `'P'` and you found the index with `string.find('P')` already.

If you mean substracting the `'P'` letter from `'ABP'` then use:

```
new_string = 'ABP'.replace('P','')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you slice strings like this `s = string[0:2]`

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'ABP'
p_index = string.index('P')
s = string[p_index]
print(s)

string = 'ABP'
p_index = string.find('P')
s = string[p_index]
print(s)
```

maybe you can try it like this two